# count multiple tables in sql

Tags: sql, database, multiple-tables

I have a database that has a table for each day making it a huge database consisting of so many months and even years. Now, I wanna count the records of all the tables in each month. I mean, I want the count of all the records in all tables but monthly apart.

I already used this query:

```
select
(SELECT count(*) FROM [Rayanparsi].[dbo].[TransRecordTable_14000601] where mti=200 )+
(SELECT count(*) FROM [Rayanparsi].[dbo].[TransRecordTable_14000602] where mti=200 )+
(SELECT count(*) FROM [Rayanparsi].[dbo].[TransRecordTable_14000603] where mti=200 )+...
```

witch is useful but it won't give me the result for each month. it gives me the total count of all the tables existing in the query.
Thx everyone.

Comment: Hi - having a table per day is normally a really bad design and it's generally much better to have a single table with a "date loaded" (or similar) column. Assuming you can't change the design, how do you know which tables apply to which month? From the sample query it seems like the table names are sequential and don't contain any information about the date they refer to

Comment: Assume this MS Sqlserver? Dynamic sql is a  way you can do theis sort of thing, when someone chooses this approach. Plenty of example to do something similar, but it's basically code.

Comment: How do you know which month a table belongs to? Does 14000601 imply something?

Comment: Yes the design is not so appealing but that's just protocols and I can't change that unfortunately. by the way 14000601 is the date of the very day that the table belongs to. So the tables are named after the date of that day and also they are named and ordered based on date very neatly.

Comment: How is “14000601” a date?

Comment: It is not an AD date. It is a different type of date. But in terms of separators, we had to omit them to name the tables. Actually it has to be written something like this: 1400/06/01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to hard-code the relevant year/month/day values into your query against each table, UNION all individual table queries together and then query that result to give what ever final result you need.

This SQL will give you an example of how to do this; obviously you may need to adjust it to meet your exact requirements

```
WITH ALL_DATA AS 
(SELECT '1400' TABLE_YEAR, '06' TABLE_MONTH, '01' AS TABLE_DAY, count(*) AS TABLE_COUNT FROM [Rayanparsi].[dbo].[TransRecordTable_14000601] where mti=200
 UNION
 SELECT '1400' , '06', '01', count(*) FROM [Rayanparsi].[dbo].[TransRecordTable_14000602] where mti=200
 UNION
 SELECT '1400' , '06', '01', count(*) FROM [Rayanparsi].[dbo].[TransRecordTable_14000603] where mti=200
)
SELECT TABLE_YEAR, TABLE_MONTH, SUM(TABLE_COUNT)
FROM ALL_DATA
GROUP BY TABLE_YEAR, TABLE_MONTH
;
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much. You just saved me a lot of time and work. That got me to the result that I wanted... I just added all the tables to the query considering the format of the query. but I was wondering if I can add one more task to the query witch is summing the values of a field that exists in all tables. is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, just add “, sum (column_name)” after the count in each query